# React native SVG building pie chart with Path

Tags: react-native, svg

I have a code that builds a SVG figure for a pie chart, using this function:

```
export const generateArc = (percentage: number, radius: number) => {
  const a = (percentage * 2 * Math.PI) / 100 // angle (in radian) depends on percentage
  const r = radius // radius of the circle
  const rx = r
  const ry = r
  const xAxisRotation = 0
  let largeArcFlag = 1
  const sweepFlag = 1
  const x = r + r * Math.sin(a)
  const y = r - r * Math.cos(a)
  if (percentage <= 50) {
    largeArcFlag = 0
  } else {
    largeArcFlag = 1
  }

  return `A${rx} ${ry} ${xAxisRotation} ${largeArcFlag} ${sweepFlag} ${x} ${y}`
}
```

Everything works fine, except when percentage is 100, the chart disappears, you can look [here](https://snack.expo.dev/7ZgGDjwvq)
I feel like that there's some miscalculation, but i don't have much experience in such things with SVGS, and i can't figure it out.

The workarounds I've found are:

- iOS: check if percentage is 100, then use 99.9, but that doesn't work for android (i've tested on real device, there's a little gap that's not filled, but on some emulators 99.9999 gives the full circle), you can check it in a snack
- For both platform just use a full circle SVG instead, if percentage is 100, but i don't like that workaround

Comment: It's simply not possible to draw a circle with a single arc. Use two (or more) arcs in that case, or a circle.

Comment: @RobertLongson but can a circle be generated using path in general?

Comment: Erm, didn't I say that already? I.e. yes, provided you use multiple arcs.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i didn't get it first time, i see now, thanks, i will look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Robert Longson I've modified the function that generates arc a bit, so now it generates 2 arcs if percentage is 100

```
const generatePath = (percentage: number, radius: number) => {
  if (percentage === 100) {
    const x = radius
    const y = radius
    // in path x has to be 0 = starting point
    return `M ${0}, ${y}
        a ${x},${y} 0 1,1 ${radius * 2},0
        a ${x},${y} 0 1,1 -${radius * 2},0
        `
  }

  const a = (percentage * 2 * Math.PI) / 100 // angle (in radian) depends on percentage
  const r = radius // radius of the circle
  const rx = r
  const ry = r
  const xAxisRotation = 0
  let largeArcFlag = 1
  const sweepFlag = 1
  const x = r + r * Math.sin(a)
  const y = r - r * Math.cos(a)
  if (percentage <= 50) {
    largeArcFlag = 0
  } else {
    largeArcFlag = 1
  }

  return `M${radius} ${radius} L${radius} 0 A${rx} ${ry} ${xAxisRotation} ${largeArcFlag} ${sweepFlag} ${x} ${y} Z`
}
```